# select the I'd from the database using CONDITIONS IN SQL

Tags: sql

select the  id  from the table using below conditions

please find the sample data in comment

Query to select the Id from the table using the following conditions.
It should satisfy all three conditions

If year is 2018 and values greater than or equal to 2000

If year is 2019 and values greater than or equal to 4000

If year is 2020 and values greater than or equal to 6000

Example id 1 and 2 have three years and met the limit conditions

The output like
Id
1
2

```
Create table A(id int ,year int,value int);
Insert into A values(1, 2018, 2000);
Insert into A values(1, 2019, 4000); 
Insert into A values(1, 2020, 6000); 
Insert into A values(2, 2018, 3000); 
Insert into A values(2, 2019, 4542); 
Insert into A values(2, 2020, 8000); 
Insert into A values(3, 2019, 3000); 
Insert into A values(3, 2020, 7000); 
Insert into A values(4, 2018, 1000); 
Insert into A values(4, 2019, 4564); 
Insert into A values(4, 2020, 7035);
```

Comment: '''Create table A(id int ,year int,value int)
 

    
    Insert into A values(1, 2018, 2000)
    Insert into A values(1, 2019, 4000)
    Insert into A values(1, 2020, 6000)
    Insert into A values(2, 2018, 3000)
    Insert into A values(2, 2019, 4542)
    Insert into A values(2, 2020, 8000)
    Insert into A values(3, 2019, 3000)
    Insert into A values(3, 2020, 7000)
    Insert into A values(4, 2018, 1000)
    Insert into A values(4, 2019, 4564)
    Insert into A values(4, 2020, 7035)'''

Comment: You can edit your question and put the sample data from your comment directly there to get better readability

Comment: i added the sample data in my comment

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  (and, Please, apply the knowledge that you are reading there.... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question as it currently stands:

> Query to select the Id from the table using the following conditions. It should satisfy all three conditions If year is 2018 and values greater than or equal to 2000 If year is 2019 and values greater than or equal to 4000 If year is 2020 and values greater than or equal to 6000

```
    SELECT id FROM a 
        WHERE year = 2018 AND value >= 2000 
            OR year = 2019 AND value >= 4000 
            OR year = 2020 AND value >= 6000;
```

Edited: as per your comments you want only Id 1 and 2:

```
    SELECT distinct id 
        FROM a 
        WHERE id in (SELECT id from a WHERE year = 2018 AND value >= 2000) 
            AND id in (SELECT id from a WHERE year = 2019 AND value >= 4000) 
            AND id in (SELECT id from a WHERE year = 2020 AND value >= 6000)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the id should have three years. Seems like This query is validating any one  of three conditions

Comment: if I add the AND operator in the where clause , it doesn't work

Comment: Can you rephrase your description of the desired output?

Comment: SELECT distinct id FROM A 
        WHERE (year = 2018 AND value >= 2000) 
           and (year = 2019 AND value >= 4000 )
            and (year = 2020 AND value >= 6000);

Comment: I tried the above query. but it doesn't work. The output ids are : 1 2

Comment: Id 1 and 2 met all three conditions

Comment: Thanks Stefan, It's working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? (question is unfortunatly a bit unclear about desired output):

```
select year, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as `ids`
from A 
where year=2018 and value>=2000
union all
select year, GROUP_CONCAT(id)  as `ids`
from A 
where year=2019 and value>=4000
union all 
select year, GROUP_CONCAT(id)  as `ids`
from A 
where year=2020 and value>=6000;
```

output:

| year | ids |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | 1,2 |
| 2019 | 1,2,4 |
| 2020 | 1,2,3,4 |

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0cabb0c5adce13cb897a5f00c8f8bbe)

When a space is needed, in stead of a `,`, you should change the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, and add `SEPARATOR ' '`, see this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=245fedbe0a3ad12a196232d63587d2c6)

Comment: The output should be below format ---> id 1 2

Comment: SELECT distinct id FROM A 
        WHERE (year = 2018 AND value >= 2000) 
           and (year = 2019 AND value >= 4000 )
            and (year = 2020 AND value >= 6000);

Comment: I tried the above query but it doesn't work

Comment: You do mean the the `,` should be a space?, see this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=245fedbe0a3ad12a196232d63587d2c6)

Comment: Nice! GROUP_CONCAT is MySql syntax, right?

Comment: Yes, it is, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat